# Dynamic Target entity Doctrine 2 and Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want dynamic entity mapping on one entity which will be used by other entities. For example, I have a File entity, which will store `MIME` type, mapping `key`, `name` etc, also an `entity_id` which will contain the id to the entity it belongs to. The mapping `key` will determine the class as this file entity will be many-to-many. So the `targetEntity` for File entity isn't fixed. How to achieve that?

File Entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * File
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class File {
    //.... Other mapping properties

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SuperClass", inversedBy="files")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $entity;
}
```

Product Entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product extends SuperClass {
    //.... Other mapping properties

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="File", mappedBy="entity")
     */
    protected $files;
}
```

But I have many other entities similar to `Product` and how do I make sure that when I call `getFiles()`, I get the files of the respective entity. I think it may work like this anyway, but is this the right way, or is there a better way?

Comment: Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better answers.

Comment: Sure, I hope now I have edited with proper information.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is a very common problem I have - how to link one entity to many others which are very similar.

**First, reevaluate:** I often find, that I don't actually need that many different entities and that they can be folded into one there by simplifying everything. We often overengineer and overcomplicate when we don't really have to (or even shouldn't)!

**If that's not an option:**
create separate relationships between File and all other (relevant) entities. Yes, your file entity will be full of relationships. Then write one general access getter that computes which entity it is connected to and returning it (either by going through all connections or it can be more involved that that [and faster] by computing it from other params (like mime type in your case).
This way you hide the complexity of all those relationsip from the rest of your code.

This option works if you just need a good enough solution. A more correct one would be to forgo doctrine relations and track IDs and related entities classes in two fields and select and instantiate the objects yourself (in the entity, ofcorse). But that's more involved and more error prone.

If you find a way to do this in a more elegant, doctrine2 backed way, please do let me (and the rest of us) know.

Comment: I just updated my question with a possible solution, I thought of this way but I haven't tried if this will work.

Comment: I will, but I don't think it will work, the super class won't contain table details.

Comment: I want also set "+" for these words **if you find a way to do this in a more elegant, please,let us know!**. 

Because now to set many relations - it's a pain for my eyes, really. I don't understand why ORM didn't make the same as made in ODM, something like discriminator type for the specific field, which describes how to resolve to multiple entities... I'm full of pain about this stuff.

My case: I have one Translation table for all the entities,and I can't join all of them to one table. I need to create all the relations, thanks to @Putr me helped with this advice. Any idea for my case?

Comment: @Nikita_kharkov_ua ORM cannot use a field like `discriminator`, because underlying DBMS is expected to have foreign key that links tables. Discriminator would simply not allow that, since it's more akin to polymorphic relationships. MongoDB simply does not have a concept of foreign keys and it's unlikely to have one in th near future. As for solution that I use, I have a "Tag" entity that can be linked from any other entity, but without bi-directional association, i.e. Tag does not know what it's linked to (you can still query it using `QueryBuilder`)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that according to my requirements, I can do with ManyToMany Unidirectional or OneToMany Unidirectional. But for bidirectional, there seems to be no solution. I have something in mind, but it will just complicate the Scenario. According to doctrines documentation, the schema Generated will be

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Feature (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    product_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE Feature ADD FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES Product(id);
```

So like I suggested in my question to extend a SuperClass, what if the super class to be an entity itself with its own table, containing a field which will store repository path, and somehow it will be processed to return the proper entity.